# Undefined variable from variable in template.php

Tags: 7, theming

In template.php I have this function.

```
function my_theme_process_page(&$variables) {
    $menu_tree = menu_tree_all_data('main-menu');
    $variables['main_menu'] = menu_tree_output($menu_tree);
}
```

It works, but SOMETIMES it shows the following notice:

> Notice: Undefined variable: menu_tree_output on bootstrap_barrio_process_page() (líne 30 of /home/myweb/sites/default/themes/my_theme/template.php).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it really happen in that code?
because error is "Undefined variable: menu_tree_output"
I see call to "menu_tree_output" function, but no menu_tree_output variable and it says variable is not defined in bootstrap_barrio_process_page

Comment: I agree with @MantasKaranauskas. The error message does not match the code. Also, there is no way to tell what goes on here until we know what value is returned by the function `menu_tree_output($menu_tree)`. What line is line 30?